# intellij "new Branch" menu item isn't active

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ IDEA, I cannot use a new branch because the menu item for creating a new branch is not active.
What needs to be done so that the menu items becomes active ?

[image]

Comment: Have you filed changes where they have not yet been committed and pushed?

Comment: What do you mean with "filed changes"  ?

Comment: Sorry, I mean *edited files* / file changes

Comment: yes... I have files in intellij which haven't committed to the local branch yet.

Comment: Technically, having uncommitted changes shouldn't stop you from checking out new branches as far as git repos are concerned. The underlying issue might be sth else.

Comment: Could you please confirm whether you have made an initial commit in your local repository? Could you please share screenshot of a Log tab under Git toolwindow?